# Meteor.js app on android: how to reinstall?

Tags: android, meteor, build

I notice that when I rerun a meteor (@1.0.5) app on an android device using

```
meteor run android-device
```

The changes I make are not being pushed. They are not being pushed in real time or even when I ctrl-C meteor at the console and rerun the command.

The only way I can get my new changes to take effect is to find the app in the apps menu in the android device, uninstall it and rerun the launch command.

Is this an expected work flow? I prefer meteor to rebuild the app on the fly and push it without my intervention, or at least reinstall it when I rerun the launch command. It does not seem to be doing neither...